# Does a lance qualify for the Great Weapon Fighting fighting style when wielded unmounted?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, fighter, fighting-style

I'm devising a character that uses a jousting lance, but without a horse. Given that the rules for lances state you need to wield them with two hands while unmounted, does that meet the requirement for the Great Weapon Fighting fighting style?

Answer (score 23):

The Great Weapon Fighting [fighting style](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#FightingStyle) states that:

> The weapon must have the *two-handed* or *versatile* property for you to gain this benefit.

A [lance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/lance) has the Reach and Special properties (as per the weapons table on page 149 of the PHB) but does **not** have the *Two-handed* or *Versatile* properties so it doesn't not qualify for use with Great Weapon Fighting.